# node.js csurf invalid csrf token

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

I'm using nom's csurf module with express. Everything were working perfectly since last 3 days. Now every time I post form I get invalid csrf token error. I'm using latest versions of csurf and express.

My app.js settings:

```
var csrf = require('csurf');
...   
app.use(csrf());
...
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals = {
        csrf: req.csrfToken(),...
```

My jade template:

```
form(role='form', method='post', action='/auth')
                            input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value='#{csrf}')
                            ...
                            input.btn.btn-success.btn-block(type='submit')
```

And here is error I always get:

```
Error: invalid csrf token
at createToken (/Users/.../.../.../.../node_modules/csurf/index.js:107:19)
at /Users/.../.../.../.../node_modules/csurf/index.js:91:7
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../.../.../.../node_modules/csurf/node_modules/csrf-tokens/node_modules/uid-safe/index.js:13:7)
at Object.ondone (/Users/.../.../.../.../node_modules/newrelic/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:177:31)
```

As I understood this error appears after I starting the server and get 'no open connections' error.

Comment: Check the order in which you have called your middleware. It is likely that you are calling your middleware in the wrong order. Ensure that your `csrf` middleware and your assignments to `res.locals` occurs before `use(app.router)`.

Comment: @adamK, I already checked it. Everything is in needed order.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem? My csrf also suddenly stopped working for whatever reason.

Comment: @Charminbear, yes, I solved this problem. You probably using secured cookies. Check this in your app.js file. I came to solution after checking cookies in my browser (They wasn't set for this site).

Answer (score 0):

You try:

In Router

```
var csrf = require('csurf');

var csrfSecured = csrf();
router.use(csrfSecured);

router.get('/auth', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('user/auth', {
        ...
        csrfToken: req.csrfToken(),
        ...
    }
}
```

In views:

```
input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value='#{csrfToken}')
```